# Equations of the same plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Are 
\begin{equation*}
-x-4y+3z=-9~\text{and}~x+4y-3z=6 
\end{equation*}
equations of the same plane? I graphed them and they look the same, but I am not sure. Thanks

Comment: Is it true that $$9 = x+4y-3z = 6$$

Comment: Try looking at the point $(6,0,0)$. It is on one plane, but not the other.

Comment: By " the same" you undoubtedly mean "parallel", which means that they are "the same" up to translation by some vector - and yes, that's the case here because both can be obtained by sliding the plane $x+4y-3z=0$ down the z-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Two equations $$ax+by+cz = d$$ and $$a'x+b'y+c'z=d'$$ represent the same plane if there exists $\lambda \neq 0$ such that $(a',b',c',d') = \lambda(a,b,c,d)$. In other words, if you can re-scale one equation to get the other one. This don't happen here.

Comment: **Q1.** So if one equation can be obtained by multiplying another with the scalar (re-scale) i.e. [row multiplying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Row-multiplying_transformations), **then only** they represent same plane?  This will result in $RankA=Rank[A|B]<n$ for $n$ variable system $[A|B]$. **Q2.** Right? **Q3.** But (I want to know) does that mean: $RankA=Rank[A|B]<n$ always imply $2+$ equations must represent same plane? My primary feeling is that, its not like that, because $RankA=Rank[A|B]<n$ may happen due to linear combinations, not just re-scaling. Am I right?